# How to use CSS Stylesheet on SSRS 2017

Tags: css, reporting-services

Anyone have any documents, articles on how to use CSS stylesheets on SSRS 2017?
We upgraded and some of our reports are wrapping text in columns when rendering, fit ok on SSRS 2012.

Comment: Is [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac349c8c-d1cf-47a1-8402-1cc739caead8/can-we-use-css-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices) of any help? I just googled, i dont have any knowledge about the subject itself.

Comment: I am looking to change the default font used to render an RDL, not modify the look and feel of the "Report Manager" web site.